# Weighting based on Standard Deviation, no negative values.

Tags: average, standard-deviation

I have a list of bond spreads, and I want to rank/weight them based on the standard deviations of those spreads. There are 42 samples, and so far I have

$$rank=\frac{x-\bar{x}} {\sigma}$$

to pull the number of standard deviations from the mean that the data point comes from. From there, I would like to weight those deviations (such that the largest negative deviation has the lowest weighting, while the largest positive deviation has the highest weighting) such that the weightings sum to 100%, with no negative values.

Comment: Er...why are you subtracting $\sigma$ and dividing by $\overline{x}$? You should be subtracting $\overline{x}$ and dividing by $\sigma$ to count deviations in units of standard deviations. Of course those are *signed* deviations, so perhaps you might take the absolute value of these quantities or something?

Comment: You're right, fixed that, edited the post, thanks. But the ranking problem persists. Taking absolute values makes the lowest ranked value have a high, positive weighting--I would like to minimize the lowest ranked values' weight.

Edit: In fact, it looks like that breaks the weighting formula entirely. Not sure how to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what the goal of the weighting is or why it should not be negative it is hard to answer, but if you just want to make it non-negative you can take the exponent of the rank you proposed ($e^{rank}$). However this will scale the values in a non-linear way, which may or may not be appropriate for your specific needs.

Comment: This is information that will feed into an investment portfolio, with the weightings informing dollar weights. I would like to avoid short selling, so normalizing negative weights to be very small positive/zero weights would be ideal. Can't figure out an algorithmic way to assign weights thus.

Edit: Post edited to reflect this

Comment: @msfinance Why not just take the maximum of the negative weights with zero? Or you could use a sigmoid function that decays to zero at $-\infty$, such as $\frac{e^x}{e^x+1}$. What should the weight do as the rank goes to $+\infty$? Should it go to $1$?

Comment: Yeah, goes to 1 at $+\infty$. That looks like it might work, let me test it out ...